# new setting switch case arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

I have 2 buttons and an lcd. The buttons are used to lower/raise the threshold of a microphone sensor.
My old sensor code is:

```
 int val = analogRead(0);
 switch(val)
 {
case 600:
{
    digitalWrite(FLASH_PIN, HIGH);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(FLASH_PIN, LOW);
    break;
}
```

as you can see I use `switch` and when the microphone rises to `600` I trigger the LED,

My question is: how can I make the code to get the new setting of the threshold via buttons?
So instead of `case 600` it should be `case 'new setting'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, using 'if' is more versatile than 'switch'. For example, if the value was 601, you'd still want the LED to flash, but your current code wouldn't do it.

What you need is a persistent variable that's defined outside of the functions. You can't define it in setup() or else it won't be recognized in loop(). You then look for changes in the values read from the switches, and adjust the variable accordingly. For example:

```
int threshold=600;
int prevUp=LOW;
int prevDown=LOW;
const int increment=10;
const int flashPin=13;
const int upButtonPin=12;
const int downButtonPin=11;
const int micPin=0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(flashPin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(upButtonPin,INPUT);
  pinMode(downButtonPin,INPUT);  
  digitalWrite(flashPin,LOW);
}

void loop() {
  int up=digitalRead(upButtonPin);
  int down=digitalRead(downButtonPin);
  if (up==HIGH && prevUp==LOW) threshold+=increment;
  if (down=HIGH && prevDown==LOW) threshold-=increment;
  threshold=constrain(threshold,0,1023);
  int (analogRead(micPin)>=threshold){
    digitalWrite(flashPin, HIGH);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(flashPin, LOW);
  }
  prevUp=up;
  prevDown=down;
}
```

Note that how I've written it here, the threshold will reset to 600 each time the device is turned on. If you want the threshold to be persistent even when the device is unplugged, you'll need to use the Arduino's EEPROM. But that's more complicated. Let me know if you'd like me to get into it.